# Android Generic Superclass

Tags: java, android, generics

I have the following generic activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   protected abstract Fragment createFragment();
.
.
.
```

and want to implement

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


public class PhotoDisplayActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

   @Override
   protected Fragment createFragment() {
       return PhotoDisplayFragment.newInstance();
   }

}
```

But this is throwing `incompatible types: PhotoDisplayFragment cannot be converted to Fragment`. Changing the `SingleFragmentActivity` return type to a `PhotoDisplayActivity` would obviously defeat the purpose of it being generic.

What am I messing up here?

Thanks,
Otterman

Comment: You need to be more specific about your errors. Anyway, I would guess that you're mixing up `Fragment` imports. That is, you've got `android.app.Fragment` imported in one place, and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in another.

Comment: Edited to include relevant import statements and error message

Comment: Look in your `PhotoDisplayFragment` class. You've apparently got `android.app.Fragment` imported there.